# How does starting with infinite value while finding the lowest value in a list works in Python?

Tags: python

```
>>> lowest_path_cost = float('inf')
>>> # pretend that these were calculated using some worthwhile algorithm
>>> path_costs = [1, 100, 2000000000000, 50]
>>> for path in path_costs:
...   if path < lowest_path_cost:
...     lowest_path_cost = path
...
>>> lowest_path_cost
1
```

Hi, I came across this question here, and  was wondering why
`if path < lowest_path_cost: lowest_path_cost = path` would generate the lowest value in the list since all of them are smaller than infinity

Why would this help to find the lowest value? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because if you don't start with an initial assumption your code will fail when the `path_costs` list contains only one item. The safest assumption is positive infinity; as no number can be greater than that.

Comment: You need a starting value for the first comparison which is guaranteed to be higher than anything you may legitimately encounter…

Comment: it's a convenient value to choose to initialize your `lowest_path_cost`, which is basically acting as an accumulator. Think what happens if you set it to `None`, then you have to add extraneous logic, like `if lowest_path is None or path < lowest_path_cost`... Alternatively, you can start with the *first* item, which is easy enough, but will be less clean (have to handle the case of only *one* item, and it's not very clean if you want to handle arbitrary iterables not just lists).

Comment: Of course, you *should* just use `min`.

Comment: Thank you guys for answering! I understand it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Selcuk points out (although I would correct it a bit) you *might* need to have an initial value if you want to loop over *all* of the items in one loop.

You can consider this question; say you have a list with a 1000 numbers i.e you cannot comprehend looking at all of them at one time. How would you with a pen and paper find the lowest number? One of the ways is to do the following:

1. write down the first number in the list (call that `x0`)
2. Check the next number, `x1`, and see if `x1<x0`
3. If that is the case, set `x0=x1` i.e `x1` is now the new smallest number
4. Repeat (2)-(3) for all occuring numbers

in python that would be

```py
#example 1)

numbers = [10,5,2,15,20....] #Long list
x0 = x[0] #first number
for x1 in numbers[1:]: #for all the remaining numbers [5,2,15,20...]
    if x1 <x0: #check if the current number is less than the smallest number
          x0 = x1 #if it is - update the smallest number to x1
```

but if you dont want to initialize using the first number in the list, you can initialize it with a number you know is greater than *any* number in the list which is inifinity

```py
#example 2)
numbers = [10,5,2,15,20....] #Long list
x0 = float("int") # 'first' number
for x1 in numbers: #for all the remaining numbers- note we have removed the slicing [1:]
    if x1 <x0: #check if the current number is less than the smallest number
          x0 = x1 #if it is - update the smallest number to x1
```

You may then ask - why does it have to be inifinity? Lets try take an example with a big number, say 50.000. If all of the items in the list is greater than 50.000, we'll get that the smallest item in the list is 50.000 which is *wrong*:

```py
numbers = [100_000,200_000] #List with big numbers
x0 = 50_000 # Chose a too small number for initial-value
for x1 in numbers: #for all numbers
    if x1 <x0: #None of the numbers in the list fulfill this check i.e x0 is never updated!
          x0 = x1 
print(x0)
#50_000
```

thus the only "number" to be considered a valid initial value for *all* lists is

a) The first number in the list (example 1)

b) infinity (example 2)

Note, example 2 does *not* break when we have only one item in the list - it breaks if we have zero items in the list.

But luckily we can avoid all this just by calling `min(numbers)` as @juanpa.arrivillaga says

Comment: This is very clear and helpful. Thank you!